# How to implement a generalized data structure Table<TRow, TColumn, TValue>

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

What I try to do: On the basis of generic collections of the .NET platform, implement the generalized data structure `Table<R, C, V>`, where:

`R` - row key
`C` - column key
`V` - value

This data structure must provide access to the values stored in it on the keys `R` and `C` with complexity O(1).
Demonstrate working with this data structure by creating a `Table<FootballTeam, Tournament, HashSet<int>>` collection object.
`FootballTeam(title, city, foundationYear)`
`Tournament (title, international: boolean, foundationYear)`
`HashSet<int>` - contains the years when a given `FootballTeam` won the `Tournament`.
Also give some of your own example of using this data structure

I don't know how to do it next and if I'm doing it right, I want to create a dictionary in the dictionary.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace task5_virobnicha
{
    public class FootballTeam
    {
       public  string title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string city
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int foundationYear
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public FootballTeam(string title, string city, int foundationYear)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.city = city;
            this.foundationYear = foundationYear;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{this.title} {this.city} {this.foundationYear}";
        }
    }

    

    public class Tournament
    {
        public string title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public bool international
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int foundationYear
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Tournament(string title, bool international, int foundationYear)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.international = international;
            this.foundationYear = foundationYear;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{this.title} {this.international} {this.foundationYear}";
        }
    }





    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            FootballTeam team1 = new FootballTeam("Vorskla", "Poltava", 1955);
            FootballTeam team2 = new FootballTeam("Desna", "Chernihiv", 1960);
            FootballTeam team3 = new FootballTeam("Dinamo", "Kyiv", 1927);
            FootballTeam team4 = new FootballTeam("Zorya", "Luhansk", 1923);
            FootballTeam team5 = new FootballTeam("Karpati", "Lviv", 1963);

            Tournament tourn1 = new Tournament("EURO2012", true, 2012);
            Tournament tourn2 = new Tournament("UEFA", true, 2010);
            Tournament tourn3 = new Tournament("OblastTourn", false, 2014);
            Tournament tourn4 = new Tournament("ChampUkr", false, 2005);
            Tournament tourn5 = new Tournament("SyhivChamp", false, 2019);

            HashSet<int> myHash1 = new HashSet<int>();
            myHash1.Add(2012);
            myHash1.Add(2013);
            HashSet<int> myHash2 = new HashSet<int>();
            myHash2.Add(2019);
            myHash2.Add(2010);
            myHash2.Add(2015);
            HashSet<int> myHash3 = new HashSet<int>();
            myHash3.Add(2015);
            HashSet<int> myHash4 = new HashSet<int>();
            myHash4.Add(2005);
            myHash4.Add(2015);
            HashSet<int> myHash5 = new HashSet<int>();
            myHash5.Add(2019);
            myHash5.Add(2020);




            FootballTeam[] listOfTeams = new FootballTeam[] { team1, team2, team3, team4, team5 };
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfTeams.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(listOfTeams[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

            Tournament[] listOfTornaments = new Tournament[] { tourn1, tourn2, tourn3, tourn4, tourn5 };
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfTornaments.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(listOfTornaments[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

            

            HashSet <int>[] listOfHashSet = new HashSet <int>[] { myHash1, myHash2, myHash3, myHash4, myHash5 };


            foreach (int a in myHash1)
            {
                Console.Write(a);
                Console.Write(" ");
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (int b in myHash2)
            {
                Console.Write(b);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (int c in myHash3)
            {
                Console.Write(c);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (int d in myHash4)
            {
                Console.Write(d);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (int e in myHash5)
            {
                Console.Write(e);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Work with dictionary");

            Dictionary<FootballTeam, Tournament> My_dict1 =
                       new Dictionary<FootballTeam, Tournament>();

           
           for(int i =0;i< listOfTeams.Length;i++)
            {
                My_dict1.Add(listOfTeams[i], listOfTornaments[i]);
            }

            



           foreach(var item in My_dict1)
           {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
           }
           Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");


            Dictionary<Dictionary<FootballTeam, Tournament>, HashSet<int>> My_dict2 =
                        new Dictionary<Dictionary<FootballTeam, Tournament>, HashSet<int>>();


            foreach (var item in listOfHashSet)
            {
                foreach(var item2 in item)
                {
                    Console.Write(item2);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                
            }

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

           

            Console.WriteLine();

            

            Console.WriteLine(My_dict1.ToList()[0]);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? "Help me" is not a question.

Comment: Is *Amortized* O(1) OK? If so then simply combine the R and the C keys into a single key and use a dictionary from that key to the value.

Comment: I edited the question), sorry